# Global table lock mysql

Tags: mysql

I'd like to lock a mysql table with my php script, so that no other script that attempts to execute writing queries on that table is allowed to proceed until the original script unlocks the table.

How to do that? (hopefully with some fail safe method).

I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
test1.php

<?php

include 'init.php';

$q = "LOCK TABLE vars WRITE";
mysql_query($q);

echo "Table locked for writing (you wish)\n";

sleep(10);

$q = "UNLOCK TABLE vars";
mysql_query($q);

?>

test2.php

<?php

include 'init.php';

$q = "INSERT INTO vars VALUES ('test', '2016-01-01 00:00:00')";
$rows = mysql_query($q);

echo "Done!";

?>
```

1. I execute test1.php.
2. Two seconds later (but not sooner than receiving 'you wish' message fronm test1.php) I execute test2.php.
3. The result: the new row is added immediatelly, not 8 seconds later. The desired result: add the new row 8 seconds later.

Comment: This is a great place to start https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: What have you already tried? No-one's going to write it for you!

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to do this?  There may be very good reasons, but if you're concerned about [isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) then perhaps *transactions* are a better solution?

Comment: @MegaTron: Lock Table does not work.

Comment: @Eggyal: I maintain a global integer value for the database that is increased after 'a packet' of statements is executed. Each packet must execute as one atomic operation, otherwise the global value might be screwed up.

Comment: @tobi85: it definitely sounds like transactions are what you need, then.

Comment: How can I use global table locks with transactions?

Comment: The point is that with transactions you *don't need* to globally lock tables.  Your "packet" of statements is executed "atomically", in isolation from any concurrent statements.

Comment: For various reasons I am stuck with MyIsam and I can't use transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test examples actually work as desired - I only needed to I correctly configure the privileges of the mysql yuser running these scripts. The mysql user in question did not have LOCK TABLES privilege and the 1st statement in test1.php was actually raising a silent error message which I did not check for.