# Lock a MyIsam table across connections

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of mysql statements (that work on one MyIsam table only) in my PHP script and I don't want to execute these statements concurrently at any time, regardless of how many connections are being used.

For example, two different clients execute the php script on my server and the script opens one mysql connection per each request. I want first to execute the entire bunch of statements in the 1st request and only when this is completed, to execute the bunch of statements in the 2nd request.

I tried:

1. using "START TRANSACTION" before the bunch of statements => the table is MyIsam and must stay so, so this has no effect.
2. using "LOCK TABLE t WRITE" before the bunch of statements => locks are not maintained across connections so this doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: probably a better question for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: *"locks are not maintained across connections so this doesn't work"* What do you mean?  If a table is locked, all other connections trying to access the table will simply block, and wait for the table until the lock is released or the connection holding the lock disconnects.

Comment: I provided a test example showing that it doesnt work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480842/global-table-lock-mysql. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, I was doing something wrong.